# How to hide .NET error box?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a number converter with operations (like addition subtraction). But it's giving a .NET messagebox (It's actually catching error but it's showing).

*PS:*

> The Error :'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll,
>
> Info about error : Input string was not in a correct format.

I tried this:

```
int sayi1 = 0;
int sayi2 = 0;
int sonuc = 0;

try
{
    sayi1 = Convert.ToInt32(ilkSayi.Text);
    sayi2 = Convert.ToInt32(ikinciSayi.Text);
}
catch(FormatException ex)
{
    hata_labeli.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
    hata_labeli.Text = "Tam sayı yerina başka bir değer girilmiş!";
    throw ex;
}
```

This exception handler works fine but it shows this (Sorry but this photo is Turkish):

[image: THE ERROR PHOTO]

How can I hide this messagebox?

The exception handler is catching the error look these photos:

[image: WITHOUT ERROR (look to HATA):]

[image: WITH ERROR (look to HATA):]

Comment: Remove the `throw ex` line as you have handled the exception.

Comment: Using exceptions to control program flow is a _very bad_ way of programming. `int.TryParse` FTW.

Comment: @UweKeim <sarcasm> What are you talking about `Java` uses this all the time! </sarcasm>

Comment: I feel as if the winforms approach is an attack on me. I feel unsafe.

Comment: *If* you ever do want to rethrow an exception you should write `throw;` and not `throw ex;`. The reason is that doing the latter will reset the call stack to the point where you rethrow and doing this will make it difficult to debug where and why the original exception was thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `TryParse` as suggested, the problem goes away, and you also gain the ability to have a specific message for each value, though you would have to add code to handle them both being invalid:

```
int sonuc = 0;
int sayi1;
int sayi2;

if (!int.TryParse(ilkSayi.Text, out sayi1))
{
    hata_labeli.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
    hata_labeli.Text = "Tam sayı yerina başka bir değer girilmiş!"; // ilkSayi message
}    
else if (!int.TryParse(ikinciSayi.Text, out sayi2))
{
    hata_labeli.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
    hata_labeli.Text = "Tam sayı yerina başka bir değer girilmiş!"; // ikinciSayi message
}

// use the values..
```

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, I used inline variables in the `out` statements which aren't supported by earlier versions of C#. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: And the second statement must be else if.

Comment: Always glad to help!